# How to fix multiple creating sessions apollo server ssr

Tags: javascript, express, apollo, apollo-server

Well. When init my first load ssr web site sessions are created for each request to graphql. so in my db i see 4-7 saved sessions. How can I fix it.
And problem with middlewares. For ex auth middleware create a lot of tokens after sending them to client

```
app.use(authMiddleware)

   app.use(session({
        genid:  () => uuid(),
        secret: 'squirrel',
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
        },
        store,
        resave:            true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    }))
app.use('/graphql', graphqlUploadExpress({
        maxFileSize: 10000000, maxFiles:    10
    }), graphqlHTTP(async(req) => ({
        schema:   graphQlSchema,
        graphiql: true,
        context:  {
            req
        }
    })))
```